# I have issue with ADTs with Jcreator

Tags: jcreator

I'm using Jcreator
my code is :

```
import ADTs.*;
```

public class ahad1 {

```
/**
 * Creates a new instance of <code>ahad1</code>.
 */
public ahad1() {
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    {
     Array a1 = new Array(20,5);
     int b = a1.getBase();
     int l = a1.getLength();
     System.out.println("Base = " + b + "  " + "Length = " + l);
     System.out.println("The elements of a1 are: ");
     for(int i=b; i<(b+l); ++i)
     {
     a1.put(i, i*4);
     System.out.print(a1.get(i) + " ");
     }
     Array a2 = new Array(20,5);
     a2.assign(a1);
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("The elements of a2 are: ");
     for(int i=b; i<(b+l); ++i)
     System.out.print(a2.get(i) + " ");
     a1.setBase(10);
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("The new base is: " + a1.getBase());
     }


      }
      }
```

but error show :

```
 --------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
    C:\Users\Dhman\Desktop\ahad\ahad1.java:9: error: package ADTs does not exist
    import ADTs.*;
   ^
  C:\Users\Dhman\Desktop\ahad\ahad1.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
  Array a1 = new Array(20,5);
  ^
     symbol:   class Array
     location: class ahad1
     C:\Users\Dhman\Desktop\ahad\ahad1.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
     Array a1 = new Array(20,5);
           ^
       symbol:   class Array
       location: class ahad1
     C:\Users\Dhman\Desktop\ahad\ahad1.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
     Array a2 = new Array(20,5);
     ^
      symbol:   class Array
       location: class ahad1
        C:\Users\Dhman\Desktop\ahad\ahad1.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
       Array a2 = new Array(20,5);
           ^
       symbol:   class Array
       location: class ahad1
       5 errors

       Process completed.
```

Comment: You have not explained what the problem is?

Comment: C:\Users\Dhman\Desktop\ahad\ahad1.java:9: error: package ADTs does not exist
    import ADTs.*;

Comment: You need to explain what your code is supposed to do. Readers will not figure it out and they will not get excited to help you

Comment: I have homework and these are what I need do :

Comment: Exercise 1:
Write a Java program that will test the Array class in the ADTs package to verify all of its functionality by following these steps:
1. Import the ADTs package.
2. Create an Array object a1 with base 5 and length 20.
3. Assign the base of a1 to a variable b.
4. Assign the length of a1 to a variable l.

Comment: 5. Display the base of a1.
6. Display the length of a1.
7. Initialize the elements of a1 to the following values 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 68 72 76 80 84 88 92 96
8. Display the elements of a1.
9. Create another Array object a2 with base 4 and length 10.
10. Assign the elements of a1 into a2.
11. Display the elements of a2.
12. Modify the base of a1 to 10.
13. Display the base of a1.

Comment: Your output should be as the following:
Base = 5  Length = 20
The elements of a1 are:
20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 68 72 76 80 84 88 92 96
The elements of a2 are:
20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 68 72 76 80 84 88 92 96
The new base is: 10

Answer (score 0):

how I import ADTs.*
I can't do that